# Как вывести массив типа int в listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

Как вывести массив в listbox в WinForms?

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Transport kiaRio = new Transport(new Car());
                   
        //---------------------------------------------
        var reisKia = kiaRio.TakingsLastYear(1,2,3);
        var reisKiaZ = kiaRioZ.TakingsLastYear(15,88,3);
      
        //---------------------------------------------
        int[] reisesYears;
        
        reisesYears = new int[1];
        reisesYears[0] = reisKia;
        reisesYears[1] = reisKiaZ;
        //-----------------------------------------------
        //listBox2=?
        
        

    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не используйте конструктор для вставки своего кода, используйте обработчик Form.Load.

Answer (score 0):

У `ListBox` есть свойство `DataSource`. К `DataSource` можно забиндить любой `IEnumerable`. Использовать следующим образом:

```
myListBox.DataSource = myArray;
```